# Is it possible to find two differentiable functions such that the following inequalities hold?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\gamma > 0.$ Is it possible to find two differentiable functions $f, g:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$g(T)e^{-\gamma f(T)} \geq g(0)e^{-\gamma f(0)}$$
and
$$\gamma f'(t) - \frac{g'(t)}{g(t)} \geq C > 0\quad\text{for almost every $t \in [0,T]$}$$
for some constant $C >0$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $g(x) := -1$ and $f(x) := \frac{x}{\gamma}$ will do (with $C = 1$).

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping not to lose the $\gamma$ though, do you know if there's a way.

Comment: Yes, just replace my $f$ with $f(x) = x$. But then $C$ will be $\gamma$, is that a problem? If neither $f,g$ and $C$ may depend on $\gamma$, you may think about editing your question.

Comment: Thank you. I think that is fine.